# Why do groups not respect the parent's padding, except at the top level?

Tags: layout, padding, vega

What exactly is the behavior of padding for group marks in Vega? At the top-most level the children groups respect the top-level padding, but this doesn't seem the case for the children's children, they don't respect their parent's padding.

For example, here I would expect to get a rectangle centered in a rectangle centered in another rectangle:

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamVAkAzGmTSgyAJzYMcxkBEzmA1mvRMANkij2QAXy8ylZcSQXCDQAbVBAhCcQTCRTMjhMAH14QyxpEGIghicAFgAGfN8IpCj1WPjEpIB3GgATegyslxy0AGZC4o1S6Jc4Uhck-KScJDq6mnEjGWbW1AA2XK7I3v64QYBGEbGJqYzLOqRMaI2CACYAAgAqC76Boe3xyaNlnvU79aSzx93pkAOjicCLlrrc1oNhqMnntXmV0B8ISk4GlMPscIdjuU4glkqkyFgLgBaC5nK4Ih5Q37eKQlOEgcnDWoNGBojHRCo4mr1ehEklk8EUnbPam01b3LZMxoyAGY+ECxncmC80nkraU4WwsWfLZ49LS9GA97ypEo5X88U-DUAXRkkpZqFA-kCLiN9wVzOpGGR+NRDpshmdrs+w11qN8IHVez9TqCQcRkZeMjcAE8LL7QEwLOI6iF0HoWhAWTo4OJjqY0HYcuHkKZ7LnwjFkzhomYLFY-AGgvXRXGvlyPfq2b2JYqzeTvgmRd06eOTT7WYa5RbQ2OBROhTCbSAS7o6k5QDL9yA7dYYy6l9r+41w6HT53z-SBTrvelw5Po-fh5aYX47GxHNYszRKYcB1J6tgOHAADyoxQHQyaAdkTj5JQAg+NWcR1mEoCYE2LbmJYGQ7mwe7WIe1gnh+ASxhegzfCeN4vum-rUQ+s63m+G5GFRga0X2k7hhB-5HkB6iuK0gl-o4MHuPBiEtMhqHoV4VoqV4QA)

Instead each rectangle seems to be anchored at the origin of the top-level coordinate system.

Note that replacing `"padding": {"signal": "level_2_padding"}` with `"padding": {"value": 0}` doesn't seem to have any effect, so I'm not even sure if inner groups *can* have padding?

How can I best implement nested groups that respect the parent's padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no padding property on a [Group mark](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/group/). Instead, you can access group properties using [Field Values](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/types/#FieldValue). Something like the following should work.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamVAkAzGmTSgyAJzYMcxkBEzmA1mvRMANkij2QAXy8ylZcSQXCDQAbVBAhCcQTCRTMjhMAH14QyxpEGIghicAFgAGfN8IpCj1WPjEpIB3GgATegyslxy0AGZC4o1S6Jc4Uhck-KScJDq6mnEjGWbW1AA2XK7I3v64QYBGEbGJqYzLOqRMaI2CACYAAgAqC76Boe3xyaNlnvU79aSzx93pkAOjicCLlrrc1oNhqMnntXmV0B8ISk4GlMPscIdjuU4glkqkyFgLgBaC5nK4Ih5Q37eKQlOEgcnDWoNGBojHRCo4mr1ehEklk8EUnbPam01b3LZMxoyAGY+ECxncmC80nkraU4WwsWfLZ49LS9GA97ypEo5X88U-DUAXRkkpZqFA-kCLiN9wVzOpGGR+NRDpshmdrs+w11qN8IHVez9TqCQcRkZeMmQpnsIVQ4RiAE8cNEzBYrH4A0E0xmVnGvlyPfq2eWJYqzeTvgmRd06Y2TT7WYa5RbQw2BU2hTCbSA4OJdHUnKAZVOQHbrDGXT3tZXGuHQwui0v6QKdd70uGAB6bgKx5eIu2E1WrpXE6-N8OZk+B88PUNX3cdgl3z8Pvx2NhHGsWZolMOA6k9WwHDgAB5UYoDoJ8-RAtB8koAQfHDZNUzCUBMGzXNzEsDIxwnWcZ2sedoy3ctvnndd919R0aNfb4NyPawDHWCC-TzYj0HopMGBcX00IEGQ2D0PQIESZ8zxAD97joxVzm8R9OJobjrD4qx0HYoSRNQ9CJKkmSmP9U9t0Uz42MY1SfH-aDgOyaJXFacMoMA2D4MQ5yWicMTMK8K1gq8IA)

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "autosize": "none",
  "config": {"group": {"stroke": "black"}},
  "signals": [
    {"name": "target_height", "value": 400},
    {"name": "target_width", "value": 300},
    {"name": "level_0_padding", "value": 64},
    {"name": "level_1_padding", "update": "1/2 * level_0_padding"},
    {"name": "level_2_padding", "update": "1/4 * level_0_padding"},
    {"name": "level_0_height", "update": "target_height - 2*level_0_padding"},
    {"name": "level_0_width", "update": "target_width - 2*level_0_padding"},
    {"name": "level_1_width", "update": "level_0_width - 2*level_1_padding"},
    {"name": "level_1_height", "update": "level_0_height - 2*level_1_padding"}
  ],
  "width": {"signal": "level_0_width"},
  "height": {"signal": "level_0_height"},
  "padding": {"signal": "level_0_padding"},
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "signals": [
        {
          "name": "level_2_width",
          "update": "level_1_width - 2*level_2_padding"
        },
        {
          "name": "level_2_height",
          "update": "level_1_height - 2*level_2_padding"
        }
      ],
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"signal": "level_1_width"},
          "height": {"signal": "level_1_height"},
          "x": {"signal": "level_0_width-level_1_width - level_1_padding"},
          "y": {"signal": "level_0_height-level_1_height - level_1_padding"},
          "stroke": {"value": "red"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "group",
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "width": {"signal": "level_2_width"},
              "height": {"signal": "level_2_height"},
              "x": {
                "field": {"group": "width"},
                "mult": 0.5,
                "offset": {"signal": "-level_2_width/2"}
              },
              "y": {
                "field": {"group": "height"},
                "mult": 0.5,
                "offset": {"signal": "-level_2_height/2"}
              },
              "stroke": {"value": "blue"},
              "strokeOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll accept David's answer, but also post my own to complement David's.

Here's an alternative solution specification, like David's spec it uses the "x" and "y" group properties, but I think it's a bit simpler and closer to what I need: [Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGhDiJamVAkAzGmTSgyAJzYMcxkBEzmA1mvRMANkij2QAXy8ylZcSQXCDQAbVBAhCcQTCRTMjhMAH14QyxpEGIghicAJgAGfN8IpCj1WPjEpIB3GgATegyslxy0AGZC4o1S6Jc4Uhck-KScJDq6mnEjGWbW1Dbcrsje-rhBgEYRsYmpjMs6pExo9YJcgAIAKjO+gaGt8cmjJZ71G7Wk3Pud6ZB9w+OCAAWS7XVaDYajB67Z5ldBvcEpOBpTB7HAHI7lOIJZKpMhYM4AWjOuQu8LukO+3ikJVhIDJw1qDRgqPR0Qq2Jq9XohOJpLB5O2jypNJWt02jMaMj+GLh-IZXJgPJJZM2FKFMNF702uPSUrR-1ecsRyKVfLFX3VAF0ZBLmahQP5Ai5Dbd5UyqRgkXiUfabIYnS73sMdSjfCA1btfY6goGERGnjJkKZ7CFUOEYgBPHDRMwWKx+f1BVPp5axj6c9161ll8UK01kz7x4XdWkN43elkG2XmkP1-mNwXQ60gODiXR1JygaWTkC26zR53drUVxphkPzwuLun87Ve9JhgAeG4CMaXGwt0JkGePAbPSVVg4TNjsbEc1lm0VMcDqHtsDjgADyoxQHQ16+h+aD5JQAg+GGSYpmEoCYFmObmJYGSjuOM7TtYc5RpuZafHOa57j6DoEXenzroeN6ntutwDlCT5geRJ5bm2TZhn+r4zhBzgtGoXEvo4QHuKB77ZE4UEwbBlpeHJQA)

An important point that I have to mention is that using `layout` prevents `x` and `y` from working, that is: groups directly contained in a layout/grid may not be offset using `x` or `y`.